# Cocos2dx 3.2 Assert Failed: Layer#ccTouchesBegan override me

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to enable touch but when I touch my android device Assert Failed: Layer#ccTouchesBegan override me shows up.

Hello World initializing method:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
    Sprite* bg = Sprite::create("myBg.png");
    bg->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2);
    float rX = visibleSize.width / bg->getContentSize().width;
    float rY = visibleSize.height / bg->getContentSize().height;

    this->addChild(bg, -1);
    bg->setScale(rX, rY);

    //this->setTouchEnabled(true);
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);


    return true;
}
```

onTouchBegan method:

```
void HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan(cocos2d::Touch *pTouches, cocos2d::Event *pEvent)
{
     CCLog("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be at:

```
listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);
```

and

```
void HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan(cocos2d::Touch *pTouches, cocos2d::Event *pEvent)
```

Your function names, `onTouchBegan` and `onTouchesBegan`, do not match.

I had the same problem when I created a layer inherit from LayerColor. The same error message was shown, but when I changed inherit from LayerColor to Layer, it worked! I used cocos2dx 3.6.